# How to remove the device's frame on Android Studio's emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, frame

I am making an android app on Android Studio and I have this emulator for Nexus S.
When the emulator is running, it shows the frame of the device.
I want the emulator to show the screen of the device only.
I've tried looking in the settings but can't help it. Thanks.

Comment: For those that ended up here looking for CLI command: `avdmanager delete avd -n "android-small"` for a device named: `android-small`.

Answer (score 110):

Step 1 : Click on AVD Manager

[image: Click on AVD Manager]

Step 2 : In the pop select the EDIT AVD

[image: Edit AVD]
Step 3 : Uncheck Device Frame

[image: Uncheck Device Frame]

Comment: it is worth mentioning that with a smaller screen `Device Frame` option disappears due to a scrollbar appearing in the main section

Comment: I just updated Android Studio and no longer see that as an option.

Comment: @sdfsdf: see Edoardo's comment above

Comment: @sdfsdf: I'm using Android Studio v4.0 (latest right now) and the option do exist. It's kinda hidden though, you need to scroll it down.

Comment: Works fine, Thanks.

Answer (score 52):

### Step 1: Open AVD Manager

[image]

### Step 2: Click Edit in the specific Device emulator

[image]

### Step 3: Disable device frame option

[image]

### Step 4: Click Ok and restart the emulator

Comment: You can check out doc   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: Where in the doc does it say how to remove the device frame?

Comment: I just updated Android Studio and no longer see that as an option.

Comment: @sdfsdf: I'm using Android Studio v4.0 (latest right now) and the option do exist. It's kinda hidden though, you need to scroll it down.

Comment: I used to be able launch the emulator where there was a minimal Window around. it  It basically looked like an Android phone with the buttons on your screen.  Any idea how to bring that back?

Comment: try to restart android studio and OS