# How do you disable device frame on Android Studio 3.3?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers are for older versions of Android Studio.

When I try creating a new virtual device, I no longer see a checkbox for "Enable Device Frame" and the emulator shows the frame by default. How do I hide it?

Comment: [duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766821/how-to-remove-the-devices-frame-on-android-studios-emulators

Answer (score 5):

This has an answer here:
[How to remove the device's frame on Visual Studio Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947522/how-to-remove-the-devices-frame-on-visual-studio-emulator)

> - Open Android Device Manager from Visual Studio.
> - While your device is powered off, click the "..." in the top right corner
> - Select "Show in explorer"
> - Edit the file "config.ini"
> - Remove the skin.name and skin.path properties and save file
> - Start the device!

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQKOK.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have? The bullet points are the essential parts of the answer.

Comment: Still working in Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2. Also, in my config.ini, I had a `showdeviceframe=true`, I just needed to change that. Confusingly, the same option was present in the device settings GUI, and it was unchecked.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In my emulator option to hide frame is available here - try on your, and see if you have this potion

Comment: That switch just toggles a gray background around the device frame. I just want to see the screen of the device - no bezels.